# Multiple origin and destination in mapbox-gl

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm stuck on implementing multiple origin and destination with single map on mapbox.

For signle direction its working fine but I have a group of coordinates. Let me explain more.

E.g I have multiple set of origins and multiple set of destination.

```
[
   [
      origin_lat: 24.0000,
      origin_lng: 67.0000,
      destination_lat: 24.2000,
      destination_lng: 67.2000
   ],
   [
      origin_lat: 24.3333,
      origin_lng: 67.3333,
      destination_lat: 24.6666,
      destination_lng: 67.3333
   ] 
]
```

This is a group with 2 coordinates and I have more than two coordinates like 5 to 10 in sinple map. Is this possible to do. Also I don't want to show latitude longitude fields in map.

Please see the below code.

```
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mytoken';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [81.5158, 27.6648],
        zoom: 13
    });

    var directions = new MapboxDirections({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        unit: 'metric',
        profile: 'mapbox/driving'
    });
    map.addControl(directions, 'top-left');
    map.on('load', function () {
        directions.setOrigin([-81.476579,27.679059]);
        directions.setDestination([-81.454591,27.660815]);

        //Adding second direction but not working
    });
</script>
```